# trouble with sprintf printing or returning IP address

Tags: c

Here is the code I am trying to setup for some time now, I can't figure out why this is not working. I create a simple function with a sockaddr_in in input. I want it to return (without print) a char* containing the IP associated to the sockaddr_in.

```
char* get_ip_from_sockaddr(struct sockaddr_in client_addr)
{
int a = (client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF);
int b = (client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF00)>>8;
int c = (client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF0000)>>16;
int d = (client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr&0xFF000000)>>24;

char* ip[24];
int n = sprintf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", a, b, c, d);
printf("%s", ip); // The IP is correctly printed
return ip;
}
```

I retrieve the ip like this:

```
char* ip = get_ip_from_sockaddr(client_addr);
printf("IP CLIENT: %s\n", ip);
```

Here is the output of my programm:

```
127.0.0.1IP CLIENT: �����
```

I don't understand why this is correctly printed inside the function but when I retrieve from the function the IP is not printed.

Comment: There is standard function for doing that -- [`inet_aton`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton).

Comment: I don't understand. Why are you using an Array Of char * to store ip address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared ip as an array of *pointers*, not a char array. But more fundamentally, it's a local array which lives on the stack, and when you return from the function, the memory is released and could be overwritten with anything.

If you declare ip as

```
static char ip[24];
```

, you should be safe. With one caveat: all calls to the function will use the *same* memory for the ip string, so the result of one call will be overwritten by the next call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; but when I return the function, I still return the ip, which is then affected to the variable ip from the main function. I don't quite understand this. Following your advice, I put `char[24] ip;` instead of `char* ip[24];` which gives the expected result.

Comment: I suppose you mean `char ip[24]` but that's not safe, this memory is only allocated while the function is executing and can be overwritten by "garbage" any time later, in fact it almost certainly will. You also need to declare it `static` which means it will be pre-allocated to a fixed location.